# C++ Default constructor not inherited with "using" when move and copy constructors present

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, c++17

```
class A{

public:
    A(){};

};

class B : public A{

public:
    using A::A;

    B(const B&) =   default;
    B(      B&&) =  default;

};

B b;
```

The compiler (g++ (5.4.0-6ubuntu1) / c++11) says "no matching function for call to B::B()" and lists the copy and move constructors as candidates. If I comment those defaulted ones out then it compiles. What causes this? And what difference does it make that they are explicitly defaulted? If those 2 lines weren't there they would be defaulted anyway.

Comment: `using` doesn't bring all base constructor. default constructor is not generated in some conditions.

Comment: not sure, but once you explicitly declare a constructor (whether it is a default or not) the compiler will not automatically generate a constructor for you

Comment: note that `using A::A;` is not part of the problem here: if you comment it out, you'll get the same error.

Comment: @GianPaolo But *why* doesn't `using A::A` cause the default ctor to be inherited? I believe that is actually the core of the OP's question.

Comment: This code compiles with clang > 3.9.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/g/v8tMUI)

Comment: @PasserBy clang <= 3.8 and g++ <= 6.3 do reproduce this.

Comment: @Holt Either the flag -std=c++11 is broken, or the older compilers are broken :P Either way, if compiler version is critical, OP should post compiler version.

Comment: @PasserBy The compiler ver is g++ 5.4.0-6ubuntu1

Comment: @AdyAdy [Edit] in the question please

Comment: @Passer By Edited

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before C++17, the default constructor of the base class won't be [inherited](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) via `using`:

> All candidate inherited constructors that aren't the default constructor or the copy/move constructor and whose signatures do not match user-defined constructors in the derived class, are implicitly declared in the derived class. (until C++17)

After C++17 the code works fine.

Before that, the default constructor won't be inherited from the base class, and won't be [generated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) for class `B` because copy/move constructor are provided.

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

That's why if you comment copy/move constructor out it compiles. You can add the definition explicitly as a pre-C++17 workaround. e.g.

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(const B&) =   default;
    B(      B&&) =  default;

    B() = default;
};
```

---

<sup>The code compiles with [gcc8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9hpmp1KOSMs7DzCn).</sup>

Comment: Is really needed to put `using A::A` there? Does it make a difference if you omit it and just leave the `B() = default`?

Answer (score 6):

If you declare any constructors, the default constructor is not [implicitly generated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), you can generate it by adding a `= default` for it as well:

```
class B : public A {

public:

    B() = default;
    B(const B&) =   default;
    B(      B&&) =  default;
};
```

This has changed with [C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) (as pointed out by [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522990/377927) answer).

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor cannot be inherited, the standard explicitly says so. Quoting C++11 12.9 [class.inhctor]/3 (emphasis mine) <sup>(*)</sup>:

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor
>   having no parameters** or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly
>   declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the class where the using-declaration appears. ...

This means that for the default constructor, normal rules apply as if the `using A::A;` declaration wasn't there. So the presence of any other constructor declaration (such as the copy & move constructor) causes the default constructor not to be implicitly declared. Note that you can easily add it back by explicitly defaulting it:

```
class B : public A{

public:
    using A::A;

    B() = default;

    B(const B&) =   default;
    B(      B&&) =  default;

};
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The same wording is present in C++14 (n4140), at the same location. I can't seem to find equivalent wording in C++1z (looking through n4582)

Comment: Has this changed with newer standards?

Comment: @PasserBy I think so, the paragraph 12.9 does not exists since (at least) n4582, which is (if I remember correctly) the base of c++1z.

Comment: @Holt Yeah, I was looking through the standard and I didn't see anything similar to the quote above. I did see this though `using T::T;       // inherits all constructors from class T`